# Find relationships between items in an Excel list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel list that looks like this:

```
Project  ID
ABC      Al
ABC      Bob
ABC      Chad
DEF      Bob
DEF      Dick
```

I am trying to find a function so that I can only have the links between IDs. The final list would look like this:

```
Al Bob
Al Chad
Bob Chad
Bob Dick
```

In other words, you can see from the input that persons Al, Bob and Dick worked on project ABC. In my data, that means that they have a relationship (i.e. they worked on the same project). Thus, I would like to have one line per relationship.

Comment: Can you explain the manual methodology for generating that output from the given input? Your upper table has five entries, but the bottom table has only four.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking wouldn't the final list look like: 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-2, 2-4 which has five entries? Turning the ABC and DEF into serialized numbers can be done with a sort and a comparison formula if that is the case.

Comment: Not really. I do not wish to have 1-1 or 2-2 as they both refer to the same person. Plus, 2 and 3 both worked on project ABC so they also should be part of the list.

Comment: In your top table column one is project name, is column two person ID?

Comment: Yes, Column 1 is project name, column 2 is person id.

Comment: So the final list is relating person ID to person ID, not Project ID to Person ID?

Comment: yes, exactly. sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Understanding the problem a little better now I'd start looking at a macro that would process the first table and for each project would generate all the combinations for that project and add only those combinations to the output table that were not already present there. Knowing if the first table can be sorted by the macro would help.

Comment: Are `ID` values found on multiple projects?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a VBA solution. You'll just need to select your two columns of data (don't select the headers) and then run `Partners`.

```vb
Sub Partners()
Dim tmpColl As Collection, Projects As Object, v() As Variant, tmp As Variant
Dim s As Worksheet, k As Variant
Set Projects = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set tmpColl = New Collection
v = Selection.Value
'Use project as a dictionary key. Each key is paired with a collection of the IDs for that project.
For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
    If Projects.Exists(v(i, 1)) Then
        Set tmpColl = Projects.Item(v(i, 1))
        tmpColl.Add v(i, 2)
        Projects.Remove v(i, 1)
        Projects.Add v(i, 1), tmpColl
    Else
        Set tmpColl = New Collection
        tmpColl.Add v(i, 2)
        Projects.Add v(i, 1), tmpColl
    End If
Next i
'Create output sheet.
Set s = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
s.Name = "Output"
s.Range("A1") = "ID1"
s.Range("B1") = "ID2"
For Each k In Projects.Keys
    tmp = ListPairs(Projects.Item(k))
    s.UsedRange.Offset(s.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 0).Resize(UBound(tmp, 1), 2).Value = tmp
Next k
End Sub

Function ListPairs(C As Collection) As Variant
Dim v() As Variant, idx As Long
'Returns each pair combination from collection of items.
idx = 1
If C.Count > 1 Then
    ReDim v(1 To C.Count * (C.Count - 1) / 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
    For i = 1 To C.Count - 1
        For j = i + 1 To C.Count
            v(idx, 1) = C.Item(i)
            v(idx, 2) = C.Item(j)
            idx = idx + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End If
ListPairs = v
End Function
```

This code will output the combinations on a new sheet named "Output". If there is an existing sheet of this name, there will be an error. In this case, you may edit the line

```vb
s.Name = "Output"
```

to change the name of the output sheet.