# Find relationships between projects in an Excel list

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My problem is about finding relations between participants who have participated in different projects. In my Excel list, column1 is a list of participants and coulumn2 is a list of the project each participant has participated in. A participant may have participated in several projects.

I'm trying to find a function that enables me to find the links between the participants without the project and generate a a new list of collaboration.

My question is very similar to this one: [Find relationships between items in an Excel list](https://superuser.com/questions/749722/find-relationships-between-items-in-an-excel-list/1453126#1453126)

The question has an answer but I can't get the code to work.

- I'm not sure how to select the two columns and I can't find a guide anywhere.
- When I try to run it, the "v = Selection.Value" turns yellow and it says "i = empty".

Answer (score 1):

These are basic concepts of using the vba interface, so you're unlikely to find specific explanations - a general guide should help.

"Selection" is in the spreadsheet itself - use the mouse to select the relevant cells (the two columns containing the projects and names, eg A2:B6 in the example); then press Alt+F11 to go to the developer screen and run the macro. The selection you picked will persist and be processed by the macro.

This "yellow line" means an unhandled exception was thrown, an error in the code during runtime. In this case, it's likely because you didn't select anything, therefore there's no value to be copied.